# Python - POST to RESTful service not working

Tags: python, rest, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi to log temperature data and post this to a self-hosted RESTful API.

I'm having issues successfully posting data to the API - here's my code:

[rPi Python code]

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://doopcreations.com/raspberry/api/data'
params = urllib.urlencode({
  'item': 'temperature',
  'data': '25.00'
})

print("Posting data: " + params)

response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read()

print(response)
```

This gives me an error of:

{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item' cannot be null}}

Notes:
I've also tried to update my DB to allow NULL values - this results in only null values being inserted - ie/ it seems that my python code isn't posting data.......

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

[UPDATE]

Using "Chrome Web Store - Advanced REST client" as a testing tool:

If I send:

```
{
  "item": "temperature",
  "data": "25.00"
}
```

as the payload - I get a successful POST.

However if I send:

```
{
  'item': 'temperature',
  'data': '25.00'
}
```

as the payload - I get the error:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item' cannot be null}}
```

--

Comment: If you're getting errors from your server code, showing us the client-side code isn't very helpful.

Comment: [Background]

I've build a simple API (public with no authentication for the moment) - using slimPHP/mySQL.  I assume therefore the issue lies in how I am posting data using the python code above....

I've tested this using a RESTful tool and am able to successfully POST to the API.

Comment: Can you check the details of the rest call that succeeds. You can then turn on `from httplib import HTTPConnection; HTTPConnection.debuglevel=1` to see the python call. Compare!! Is the data structured the same. BTW I find the `requests` library much simpler for HTTP calls.

Comment: @achampion: How is `requests` any simpler for this call than `urllib2`? You still have to manually encode the JSON, and set the Content-Type, and extract the response. The only advantage is that you can make the request and send it in a single call instead of two, which saves a few characters of typing. For more complex uses, `requests` is definitely simpler, but for simple stuff like this, it doesn't add anything because there's nothing _to_ add.

Comment: @abamert agreed, but given requests meets both the simple case and complex case, and you don't have to do conditional imports if you use both python 2.X and 3.X, I default to requests even for the simple cases.

Comment: @achampion: There are often advantages to staying within the stdlib—like being able to deploy/distribute your app without third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're sending from your "Advanced REST Client" appears to be a JSON string sent as the body.

The data you're sending from your Python code is not JSON, but www-form-urlencoded.

If you'd written your service properly, it would look at the request's Content-Type and either handle www-form-urlencoded data properly, or give you an error saying that it doesn't like that Content-Type. Instead, your service just assumes nobody will ever send it anything but JSON, fails to parse the JSON and assumes you've given it null values for everything.

So, you need to fix your service.

But meanwhile, if you want to write a client that works with your broken service, you can. You have to call `json.dumps(params)` instead of `urllib.urlencode(params)`. You also can't use the single-line `urlopen` anymore. Something like this:

```
params = {
  'item': 'temperature',
  'data': '25.00'
}

r = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(params),
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(r).read()
```

---

You could simplify this a tiny bit by using the third-party [`requests`](http://python-requests.org), but I don't think it makes enough of a difference to be worth going outside the stdlib in this case. Basically, instead of this:

```
r = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(params),
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(r).read()
```

… you do …

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), 
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = r.text
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for all your help.  My API is definitely assuming JSON data is being posted.  I'll look into handling the request's Content-Type in slimPHP.  Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the dictionary directly to requests, without converting it to string with `json.dumps()` (Note: in 3.X the string will need to be explicitly converted to bytes with `.encode()`)

Comment: @achampion: According to [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), if you just pass a dictionary it will be form-encoded, not JSON-encoded, just like with `urllib2`. The example directly below that shows how you send JSON: `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))`.